# OS X: how to add a route to a hardware mac address?

Tags: networking, mac, ip, routing

When I do `netstat -rn` in Mac OS X I get some lines like the following:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
192.168.2.100      8:0:27:ad:b8:67    UHLWI          en0    182
```

which I assume indicates `192.168.2.100` will go to hardware mac address `8:0:27:ad:b8:67`

What I want to know is that if I know the hardware mac address of another machine is `8:0:27:4b:2:e7` and want to manually add the entry that maps ip address `192.168.4.100` to that mac address what should I do?

I tried

```
sudo route -n add -net 192.168.4.100/32 8:0:27:4b:2:e7
```

but it returns `route: bad address: 8:0:27:4b:2:e7`.

For some context, I am using vagrant to setup some virtual machines. Now the problem is that I have some problem with multiple vagrant machines using the same subnet (the third number in the ip address) and want to use a different subnet as my host machine (using public network). However this does not work as I cannot ping any vagrant machine with a different subnet and I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

MAC addresses are used on Layer 2, and routing happens on Layer 3 using IP addresses. To add the new route the command is

`sudo route add -net 192.168.4.100/32 <gateway ip address>`

Comment: Routing is the mapping of L3 to L2; it would actually make sense to have a raw L2 address as a route gateway. But it sounds like OP is instead confusing the routing table with the ARP table (since they're intermingled into a single table in macOS), and is really asking how to add an ARP/neighbor cache entry...

Comment: @user1686 What can I say but I agree :-D Although MAC addresses are somewhat harder to remember... then again that'd also mean that if your router goes break, you'd need to change at least gateways but also all routes in other local devices referring to the breaked one. The existence of the `-n` option suggests you could also specify the gateway with a DNS name. Interesting option, never even thought about it :-D

Comment: @user1686 Actually the initial mistake is understandable. In Linux `netstat -rn` ID:s the gateway with IP, but for some obscure reason MacOS devs have decided that it indeed should be ID:d by MAC address... _Think different_ indeed :-D Or maybe that's inherited from BSD or NextSTEP or whatever else they used to cobble it together, don't know.

Comment: No, I believe a route that actually *has* a gateway would still show its IP address (with a `G` flag) – this instead seems like a "local host" route, which is just an ARP entry in disguise. (I think it's a BSD thing to use the same table for both.) On Linux though, you can have IPv4 routes with an IPv6 gateway...

Comment: @user1686 Apparently you're right, again :-) My 2nd comment followed me running `netstat -rn` on my MacBook which is constantly connected. Repeated it now - and looks like I managed to run it the first time just at the moment the gateway was temporarily lost :-D